# Are there hydraulic torque converters that are specifically built to work like reduction gearboxes?

Tags: torque, hydraulics, power-transmission, hydrostatics

As far as I understood from [this video](https://youtu.be/PxyjjgHeDAA), there are torque converters and fluid couplers (a hydraulic clutch), but certain types of torque converters kind of work by performing the two functions at different speeds.

I just can't find hydraulic torque converters that serve as reduction boxes in bigger ratios, like gears, pulleys or transmission belts.

I guess the closest I could find was [hydrostatic transmission](https://youtu.be/qxZFSNITK-c), but this kind of transmission is used with hydraulic pumps and hydraulic motors separated, but connected. Which I couldn't find a precise amount of efficiency, but it was said to be really low.

Comment: Check my answer here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/54955/10902 as variable delivery pumps are used on certain machines instead of the "torque converter" used on cars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Torque converters as used in passenger cars commonly operate over ranges of between 2:1 and 4:1 for output RPM. The maximum torque multiplication (and rpm "division") occurs essentially at the  *stall condition* (output shaft prevented from rotating) but at stall, the efficiency is zero (all the power input is dissipated in fluid friction).

It is possible to construct torque converters with higher torque multiplication ratios than this but they are custom jobs used in things like drag racers and not commonly available.

It is also possible to place two torque converters in series to get higher overall ratios, as used in the 1963 Buick Riviera *Twin-Turbine Drive*, (sometimes known as the "Slush-O-Matic") but the power transmission efficiency of this arrangement is very poor.

A far more efficient arrangement is to combine a torque converter with a two-speed transmission, yielding the famous General Motors/Chevrolet *PowerGlide* of the mid-1960s.

Comment: You might want to indicate the year models of those vehicles to avoid some confusion.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1CpDHoOC0M

Comment: The twin turbines were coupled to different elements of a planetary gearset inside the converter. There were a whole line of them, including single, twin, and variable stator designs.  https://www.hometownbuick.com/1959-buick-twin-turbine-transmission-specifications/

Comment: @PhilSweet, will edit.

Comment: @PhilSweet thanks for the hometown buick reference. that twin turbine was a very complicated piece of machinery.