# Would connecting a small hydraulic pump to a larger hydraulic motor result in force multiplication?

Tags: pumps, hydraulics, power-transmission, hydrostatics

In a [hydrostatic transmission system](https://youtu.be/MTeJWE_Ou0g), hydraulic pumps drive hydraulic motors (basically a reverse pump).

[image: Illustration of a hydrostatic transmission system]

If you were use a smaller hydraulic pump as an input and a bigger hydraulic motor as the output, would it work like a reduction gearbox? Where the force is multiplied and the speed divided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pump and motor shown are variable which means the flow and delivery pressure can be set or chosen or feedback controlled. However, a pump should be matched so that the max capability of the motor can be provided by the pump, even though the pump output can be varied.

You can check out more detail here:

https://store.boschrexroth.com/Hydraulics/Pumps/Axial-piston-pumps/Variable-displacement/AXIAL-PISTON-PUMP_R902504834?cclcl=en_US

And the Bosch Rexroth site has so much information - was known as Mannesman Rexroth..

Answer (score 1):

A hydraulic pump in series could be theoretically be used to increase outlet pressure (assuming the inlet works at high pressure), but due to the positive displacement nature of hydraulic pups, could not be used to increase flow rate.  So you can't feed a "bigger" pump with a smaller one, nor could you feed a smaller pump with a bigger one.